# Can .class files be imported instead of .jar files?

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption

I downloaded some code for ***Attribute-based encryption*** in java and all the files are of extension `.class`. I want to import some `.class` files into my main class as there are objects in the main class for those classes, but these classes are not `.java` so they cannot be imported and objects cannot be instantiated.

I tried to convert from .class to .jar but this definitely did not work.

Comment: "I tried to convert from .class to .jar but this definitely did not work" - why not? just .zip them and you're done

Comment: There are classes that should be `.java` but they are `.class`. These classes have to be instantiated in my main class but the program says that they cannot be resolved as a type.

Comment: No, they don't need to be .java. Java is for source code, .class is for runtime, such as instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse allows you to add a class file folder to your classpath:

1. Right-click on a Java project
2. Select `Properties`
3. Select `Java Build Path`
4. Click `Add External Class Folder...` in the tabs on the right

Answer (score 2):

1. You can store all your `class` files inside `jar` (it’s just a zip after all)

Take a look for a sample: http://www.owsiak.org/running-jar-file-from-r-using-rjava-without-spawning-new-process/

2. You can use `class` files - make sure to put their location on `CLASSPATH`

Just make sure that `CLASSPATH` points at directory where your packages structure starts.